# Micro-Frontends: Importing External Remotes

Tags: webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

Using Webpack's [Module Federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/) Plugin for micro-frontend architecture, how can remotes be imported from a different repository?

Answer (score 1):

On the host, configure the host such as:

```js
// webpack.config.js
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        remotes: {
            foo: 'foo@http://localhost:3002/remoteEntry.js',
        },
    })
]

// index.js
import('foo/Bar').then(({default: Bar}) => console.log(Bar))
```

and on the remote:

```js
output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3002/', // make sure you run on the specified port
},
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'foo',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        exposes: {
            './Bar': './src/Bar',
        },
    })
]
```

You will of course want to configure some shared dependencies etc. I suggest going through the examples at https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples

Also once you start sharing some common dependencies, you will want to use async boundaries at the root of your app. Like this one https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/module-federation/src/index.js

Comment: Is there any official documentation on the `ModuleFederationPlugin` remotes option? All I can find is [this](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#promise-based-dynamic-remotes) but it doesn't actually explain anything about it.